# ¿Cómo pasar una el valor de una variable a la ejecución de un comando?

Tags: python, codificación, video

En Python.
No consigo averiguar cómo asignar una variable a la entrada de vídeo en ffmpeg.
En vez de:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/mivideo.avi videosalida.avi
```

intentar algo así:

```
ffmpef -i variableentrada variablesalida
```

Esa variable tiene que ser la ruta de un archivo de vídeo o varios.
¿Tengo que usar `concatenate` y utilizar un archivo de texto `misvideos.txt`?

Estoy haciendo pruebas con esto y no me funciona. Utilizo un archivo de texto donde está la ruta del archivo de prueba:

```
import sys
import subprocess


subprocess.call(['ffmpeg','-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', '/home/usuario/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/mylist.txt', '/home/usuario/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/output.mp4'])
```

Necesito poder usar una variable tanto para asignar los vídeos de entrada como el de salida.

En caso de variable sencilla funciona bien esto:

```
#VARIABLE SENCILLA
#FUNCIONA


import sys
import subprocess

variableinput = '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/aa.mov'
variableoutput = '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/testoutput.mov'

subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', variableinput, variableoutput])
```

En caso de concatenar no me funciona. Quiero concatenar un archivo de vídeo en negro, con un vídeo de una variable y otro vídeo en negro. Esto es lo que intento según consejos:

```
import sys
import subprocess

variableinput = '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/aa.mov'
archivos_entrada =['/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/videos_negro/negro_3fr.mp4', variableinput, '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/videos_negro/negro_5fr.mp4']


for archivo in archivos_entrada:
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg','-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', archivo, archivo + '.mov'])
```

El mensaje que me da es que no reconoce los inputs:

> /home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/videos_negro/negro_5fr.mp4: Invalid
>   data found when processing input

Answer (score 0):

A no ser que no este entendiendo tu pregunta, entiendo que se resuelve así:

```
import sys
import subprocess

variableentrada = '/home/usuario/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/mylist.txt'
variablesalida = '/home/usuario/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/output.mp4'

subprocess.call(['ffmpeg','-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', variableentrada, variablesalida])
```

En cuanto a los parámetros de ejecución del `ffmpeg` asumo que los que indicas están bien.

Por otro lado, si lo que estás buscando es procesar una conjunto de archivos, podrías eventualmente partir de una lista previamente cargada

```
archivos_entrada =['/home/usuario/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/video1.avi',
                '/home/usuario/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/video2.avi',
                '/home/usuario/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/video3.avi'
                ]

for archivo in archivos_entrada:
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg','-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', archivo, archivo + '.mp4'])
```

Comment: Gracias. La primera opción funciona muy bien así: `import sys
import subprocess

variableinput = '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/aa.mov'
variableoutput = '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/testoutput.mov'

subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', variableinput, variableoutput])`

Comment: Para la opción de concatenar no me funciona tu método. La idea es hacer algo como esto: `import sys
import subprocess

variableinput = '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/aa.mov'
archivos_entrada =['/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/videos_negro/negro_3fr.mp4', variableinput, '/home/salva/Vídeos/videos_pruebas/videos_negro/negro_5fr.mp4']


for archivo in archivos_entrada:
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg','-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', archivo, archivo + '.mov'])`

Comment: Edito en pregunta mejor...